# Storing Liquid Syntax in metafield

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm trying to work out a way to store liquid syntax in a shopify collection metafield. It can store fine in multi line text, but when i call that metafield in the template editor, it renders as text and wont actually process the liquid code. Even if i call it in a blank section as text, it just dumps the content of the metafield and wont render the liquid.

Hope that makes sense! Thanks in advnace and please let me know if i havent described it clear enough!

What am i missing here?

Tried calling the content of a metafield in shopify, of whicch the content is liquid code. That code wont render.

Comment: Need code sample or more info regarding liquid code that you tried to save and render again.

Comment: Can you give an example also of the scenario. The metafield tag is liquid, If you have a variable in liquid you can assign the metafield the value of the liquid variable, if its a liquid object I don't think you need the metafield.